# C++ template: how to use 2 typenames while only 1 is function's input?

Tags: c++, templates, copy, ostream

For a simple piece of code shown below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

static void print(const vector<int>& v) {
    copy(
        begin(v),
        end(v),
        ostream_iterator<int>{cout, ", "}
    );
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, string>> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    cout << endl << "In vector:" << endl;
    print(v);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use template programming for printing purpose, as I want to generalize `container` to be any type (`vector`, `map`, `list`, etc), and element to be any type too (`int`, `double`, etc).

```
template <typename C, typename T>
static void print(const C& container) {
    copy(
        begin(container),
        end(container),
        ostream_iterator<T>{cout, ", "}
    );
    cout << endl;
}
```

However, it won't compile:

```
In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:31:12: error: no matching function for call to 'print(std::vector<int>&)'
   31 |     print(v);
      |            ^
prog.cc:18:13: note: candidate: 'template<class C, class T> void print(const C&)'
   18 | static void print(const C& container) {
      |             ^~~~~
prog.cc:18:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:31:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   31 |     print(v);
      |            ^
```

My guess is that typename `T` is not an explicit input through function `print()`, rather, it's called by `ostream_iterator<int>{cout, ", "}` which compiler doesn't know how to deduce its type (why?).

I'm wondering how to pass both typenames (`C` and `T`) into `print()` function, although only typename `C` is the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to specify the type `T` explicitly when calling `print` (e.g. `print(v, int)`, or you write `print` such that it derives the value type of the container itself. The normal way to do this is to use `typename C::value_type`, which is present in all standard containers:

```cpp
template <typename C>
void print(const C& container) {
    using T = typename C::value_type;
    copy(
        begin(container),
        end(container),
        ostream_iterator<T>{cout, ", "}
    );
    cout << endl;
}
```

If you don't like this way, or your container may not always have a `value_type` member, then you can easily derive the value type directly:

```cpp
template <typename C>
void print(const C& container) {
    using T = std::remove_const_t<decltype(*std::cbegin(container))>;
    copy(
        std::cbegin(container),
        std::cend(container),
        ostream_iterator<T>{cout, ", "}
    );
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. Is it a good practice to print container's elements using copy() function?

Comment: Sure, it's fine. You could also use a simple range-based `for` loop though.

Comment: Yes I know `for`-loop is the easiest. I'm just wondering if there is any reason that using `copy`-based print is better than `for`-loop based print...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the second template parameter. Most STL containers have a member `value_type` for this very purpose. So your function needs to be:

```
template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type>
static void print(const C& container) {
    copy(
        begin(container),
        end(container),
        ostream_iterator<T>{cout, ", "}
    );
    cout << endl;
}
```